# Animating to negative offset makes the element jump

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The title explains it. Here's how I discovered it (was writing this as an answer): http://jsfiddle.net/tnk7K/3/

As can be seen in the example, `2` animates to the right and stops after a second. Then, after another second, `2` jumps to the far left, and `3` animates as told, only for it to happen again (and again and again and again...)

It is not caused by the later call to `css('left', 'auto')`, as that is called after the animation is completed. Besides, removing it doesn't fix the problem.

Any ideas what that is/how to solve it/am I just wrong? Googling around didn't find anything.

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you describe - using FF4.01 on Ubuntu Natty. Can I ask what setup you're using?

Comment: Chrome 12.0.742.53 on Win 7. Also happens in IE8, same platform.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve?  Do you not want the numbers to appear at the far left?

Comment: I don't understand, you have 2 animations and divs are behaving correctly. Remember, `show()` doesn't queue like `animate()`.

Comment: Correctly, on Chrome and IE at least, when the div reaches 100px to the right, on the next animation, instead of animating to `-20` to the left, it jumps to the far left. Then it animates to `-20`. So, instead of `animateRight->animateLeft`, `animateRight->weirdJump->animateLeft`.

Comment: I edited answer, in case you missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there happened some misunderstanding. You can set both `left` and `right` in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/tnk7K/5/

You see? `right` didn't change, `left` set to 0. But `width` changed.

---

EDIT:
You just have to set `left` attribute:

```
$(this).css('left', $(this).position().left);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnk7K/7/

Comment: Width changed only with the jump; before that it was animating fine. You can set `right` according to `left`, but I'm lazy and this is easier.

Comment: `left` property was set to `auto`, a non-numerical value. So jQuery assigned its value to 0. So I just defined calculated value for this style.